# Select columns names containing a key word in pandas

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, series

I have a datafame like this

```
d = {'col1': ['a', '2/1'], 'col2': ['b', 'c']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I want to know which columns contain the key '/'
since in column 'col1', the first row contains the key char '/', I hope the function could return 'col1'.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension with `pd.Series.str.contains`.

```
res = [col for col in df.select_dtypes(include=[object]) if
       df[col].str.contains(r'/').any()]

print(res)  # ['col1']
```

In this example, I explicitly isolate columns of `object` type, since numeric/date/etc series would be out of scope for your test.

Comment: @chengjunzhang, No problem, feel free to accept (green tick on left) if this answer helped.